# How do I sort a {{#each}} within an ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a list within a `{{#each}} {{/each}}`.
How would I sort this list in an ember component?

components/conversations-list.hbs

```html
{{#each model as |conversation|}}
{{conversations-item userName=conversation.contact.userName lastConversationTime=conversation.lastConversationTime profilePictureUrl=conversation.contact.profilePictureUrl id=conversation.id}}
{{/each}}
```

How would I sort this list by lastConversationTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer:

`fooSorting: ['id:desc']`

`Ember.computed.sort('model' , fooSorting)`

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.Colors = [{
  id: 1,
  color: 'red'
}, {
  id: 2,
  color: 'yellow'
}, {
  id: 3,
  color: 'blue'
}];

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Colors;
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  sorting: ['id:desc'],
  sortedContent: Em.computed.sort('model', 'sorting')
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.12.0/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.12.0/ember.debug.js"></script>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
      {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <ul>
        {{#each sortedContent as |item|}}
        <li>id: {{item.id}}: {{item.color}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </script>


  </body>

</html>
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort

Answer (score 0):

**The right way**

Use the `sortBy` function in array controller during your controller init

```
init: function() {    
  this.model.sortBy('lastConversationTime'); //Requires the model to be of Ember.Array Type
},
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_sortBy

**Or**

Use the SortableMixin:

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html

**The dirty, brute-force way:**

Inside your controller define a `sortedModels` variable and set your current model to that in the order you want it:

```
var sortedModels = [],
sortModelsBy(model, field) {
  //Add your sorting here
}
init: function() {    
  this.set('sortedModels', sortModelsBy(this.model, 'lastConversationTime'));
},
```

Inside your template call `sortedModels` instead

```
{{#each sortedModels as |conversation|}}
  {{conversations-item userName=conversation.contact.userName lastConversationTime=conversation.lastConversationTime profilePictureUrl=conversation.contact.profilePictureUrl id=conversation.id}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I found this on my search but I could not get it to work. http://balinterdi.com/2014/03/05/sorting-arrays-in-ember-dot-js-by-various-criteria.html

Comment: The first solution throws an error: this.model.sortBy is not a function TypeError. If I understood you right I put this in an Ember Array Controller: export default Ember.ArrayController.extend

Comment: can you throw a debugger in your init and observe `this.model` and confirm it is available at that time? you may have a model in `canonical` state in which you would need to add an observable on  `this.data.isFullfilled`

Comment: debugger is general js. if your not familiar with using debugger and your console, you're probably over your head with ember

Comment: Oh I thought you were referring to sth ember specific like {{debugger}} I know how to use the console and the debugger :-) Still over my head with ember though. ;-)

Comment: yeah I'm still learning ember too (thats why I gave you the brute force answer as well, sometimes its easier to start with the work around and come back when you understand everything better)

Comment: The other method throws a built error because it is not possible to define a variable in this way in an object.

Comment: ahh... try it with `this.set('sortModels', sortModelsBy(this.model, 'lastConversationTime')` I forgot you have to use ember setter after the initial definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79994/discussion-between-benedikt-and-seth-mcclaine).